# Submit button not firing and validations also not firing

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-template, angular-template, angular-validation

I'm implementing a simple Angular-CLI template form ,The submit button not firing and validations also not working ,When i press submit the values are not showing in the browser console as i expected  I  mentioned html and typescript .

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dating App</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class ="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href ="#">Matches</a></li>
          <li><a href ="#">Lists</a></li>
          <li><a href ="#">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form #loginForm ="ngForm" class="navbar-form navbar-right" (ngSubmit)="Login()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input placeholder="Email" class="form-control" type="text" required  [(ngModel)]="model.username" name ="username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password" required [(ngModel)]="model.password"  name ="password">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" [disabled]= "!loginForm.valid" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  model: any ;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  Login() {
    console.log(this.model);
  }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to print some random text inside the console.log statement?

Comment: The text will appear in the browser console .It means submit button firing

Comment: pass loginForm.value as parameter in ``Login(value)``, ``console.log(value)`` .

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you might not have added "FormsModule" in your app.module.ts .

In your `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  private model:any[]=[];

  constructor(){
  }

  private Login() {
    console.log(this.model);
  }
}
```

This solution worked for me.Hope this helps. Thanks.